# Doing same action every time document is completed

Tags: c#, gecko

I've got a problem with `GeckoWebBrowser`. I try to do the same action multiple times, everytime web document is loaded. I want to wait for the document to load, then click the button, then wait for the document to load, then click the button...

This is what I have so far:

```
private void geckoWebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GeckoHtmlElement button = (GeckoHtmlElement)geckoWebBrowser1.Document
        .GetElementsByClassName("one-class")[0];

    button.Click();
}
```

But it clicks the button only one time. How can I make the code click the button multiple times everytime the page is loaded?

Answer (score 0):

The `DocumentCompleted` is called every time the page is loaded. If it clicks only one time then there are several possible ways:

1) The page was loaded only once. 2) There is no button. You better check if it exists on he page:

```
var buttons = geckoWebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByClassName("one-class");
if (buttons.Length > 0)
{
    var button = buttons[0] as GeckoHtmlElement;
    if (button != null)
        button.Click();
}
```

So just put the breakpoint into the DocumentCompleted, and you will find out everything.
If you need to reload the page after clicking the button, call `geckoWebBrowser1.Reload();`